# Magento With Sitecore

Tags: magento2, integration

I am looking for some information and details around Magento Integration with Sitecore, what am i trying to find at the moment is:

1) Licensing requirements with Magento (this is what i see- https://www.grayboxpdx.com/blog/post/how-much-does-magento-2-cost)

2) Setup process with Sitecore.

3) Catalog management and Synchronization between two systems(Sitecore and Magento)

4) Feasibility of Magento with Sitecore

5) Any issues and risks to be considered.

6) How the Setup of Magento with Sitecore will actually work- like via APIs (REST/SOAP)?

Let me know your feedback and thoughts.

Thanks,

-Ankit